# How do I set columns/members in Kohana ORM v3

Tags: php, oop, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

```
class Model_User extends ORM {
  // columns: UserID, Name
  // public $Name ; // this didn't work
}
```

Currently I create an object:
$user = new Model_User() ;
and access columns like:

```
 $user->Name = 'My Name';
```

I'd like to have my IDE show me all the columns in the data model to avoid misspellings and to now right away what fields I can use.

How do I update my model to give my IDE the list of possible columns/properties? I tried adding the properties to the class but that broke the ORM() and no longer allowed saving. I must have overridden some base class property that gets set after reading in the column names from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [phpDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phpdoc)'s [@property](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) tag:

```
/**
   @property  string   Name     username
   @property  int      UserID   user ID (primary key)
 */
class Model_User extends ORM {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Make sure to prefix parameters with $.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, have to proceed property names with `$`

```
/**
  *   @property string $Name
  *   @property int $UserID
  */
```